# Linear Algebra Challenge Question involving Vector Spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

Let $V$ be the space of continuously differentiable maps $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $W$ be the subspace of those maps $f$ for which $f(0)=f^\prime(0)= 0.$ Let $Z$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of maps $x\to ax+b$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $V=W\oplus Z.$

In order to solve the problem, we have to show that for all $v\in V$ $$v=w+z,$$ where $w\in W$ and $z\in Z.$ I don't know why this must be true, however I can show that $W\cap Z=\{0\}$ since if $z(x)=ax+b$ and $z\in W$ then $z(0)=z^\prime(0)=0$ implies that $a=b=0.$ and so the intersection of the two subspaces must be the zero function denoted by $0.$

How do I proceed to show that every function can be represented as the sum of the functions $w\in W$ and $z\in Z$?

Comment: The key idea is that you can "use" the constant $b$ to translate the function to the origin (making $f(0)=0$), and $ax$ can make "change" the derivative so that you have $f'(0)=0$ likewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to figure out the values of $a$ and $b$ depending on $v$. Without knowing these values ahead of time, you're going to struggle.

So, let's suppose for the moment that we do indeed have $v(x) = ax + b + w(x)$ for some $w \in W$. We know that these are equal for all $x$. How can we extract the values of $a$ and $b$?

Hint: try subbing in numbers, and/or using differentiation!

Once you get these values, it shouldn't be too hard to prove.

Comment: So we have $b=v(0)-w(0)$ and $a=v^\prime (x)-w^\prime (x).$  Is this correct?

Comment: Correct indeed. You're on the right track, but you want $a$ and $b$ purely in terms of $v$, not $w$ (so that you don't need to already know the $w$ term in your decomposition). What do you know about $w$? What does membership in $W$ give you?

Comment: I have $v(0)+v(1)=a+2b.$

Comment: I don't know how you got that. I was hinting at $w(0) = 0$ (since $w \in W$), so $b = v(0)$. I'm sure you can find a similar expression for $a$.

Comment: I am sorry I got confused with the other problem, I posted! Yeah $a=v^\prime (0)$ and $b=w(0).$

Comment: I had a hunch that was the case, just as I have a hunch that you meant $b = v(0)$. :-)

Comment: Now it's time for a proof. You need to show that, given any $v \in V$, that the function $w(x) = v(x) - (v(0) + v'(0)x)$ belongs in $W$.

Comment: I was wondering how the author guessed that the space of all functions $ax+b$ will form a direct sum with $W$. If we use the dimension approach here we have that $\phi: V\to \mathbb{R}.$ Let's define $\phi(f)=f(0)-f^\prime (0)$ then we get that $\ker (\phi)=W.$

Comment: Well here, $W$ is actually of codimension $2$. Accordingly, it is the kernel of a transformation $V \to \mathbb{R}^2 : v \mapsto (v(0), v'(0))$. Note that $Z$ is the span of $2$ linearly independent vectors too: $1, x$.

Comment: Therefore, in this case, we could have taken $f(x)=1$ and then the $\text{span}\{f\}$ would have formed a direct sum with $W$, is that right?

Comment: It's codimension $2$. $Z$ is $2$-dimensional. You can't encapsulate the condition of $w(0) = 0$ *and* $w'(0) = 0$ with one linear function to the reals.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Suppose there is a decomposition $V = W \oplus Z$, so that for any $v(x) \in C^1(\Bbb R)$ we have
$$v(x) = w(x) + z(x)$$
for $w(x) \in W, z(x) \in Z$.

Now, we want to express $w(x)$ and $z(x)$ in terms of $v(x)$, and the only information available is the definitions of $W, Z$. Since $W$ is characterized by the evaluation of functions (and their derivatives) at $x = 0$, this suggests evaluating our above expression at $x = 0$, giving
$$v(0) = w(0) + z(0) .$$
Now, what does the definition of $W$ tell us about $w(0)$?